# sqlite3_column_text is very slow (C) and creates memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, sqlite

I am writing a program with C++, and I use SQLite. My code:

```
if (s == SQLITE_ROW) {
    int id = 0;
    string stem;
    id = sqlite3_column_int (selectStmt, 0);
    stem = std::string(
               reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text (selectStmt, 1))
           );
    if (id > 0)
        StemClass *st = new StemClass(id, stem);
    row++;      
}
```

**sqlite3_column_text** is very slow and it creates memory leak.

- How can I avoid this?
- Is there another way?

Comment: `"and it create memory leak"` - How do you know this?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart profile with valgrind

Comment: I think the line following that allocates a new StemClass which goes out of scope is the leak.

Comment: try initializing the string with `sqlite3_column_bytes()` as a parameter, so it won't search for the `NUL` character.

Comment: @user1095108 How use sqlite3_column_bytes()? Please give me some advise

Comment: it in the docs `http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html`.

Comment: @user1095108 Thanks for your comment. `int bytes = sqlite3_column_bytes(selectStmt, 1);    
                char c[100];     
                memcpy(c, sqlite3_column_blob(selectStmt, 1), bytes); 
                string stem(c);` It faster for me.

Answer (score 2):

For speed, you can try:

```
auto const p(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text (selectStmt, 1)));

::std::string stem(p, sqlite3_column_bytes(selectStmt, 1));
```

For leak, use a smart pointer, such as `::std::shared_ptr` or `::std::unique_ptr`. It is probably your `new` that is leaking. Previously, you were creating an empty `::std::string` instance, and then copying a new `::std::string` into it. Bad idea. Be suspicious of every `new` expression, that is not captured by a smart pointer, or some RAII scheme (such as `SCOPE_EXIT`).